# Is there a way to destroy *self* after a class is instantiated?

Tags: ruby, destructor, instantiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification of object destruction in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156248/notification-of-object-destruction-in-ruby)
>   [Ruby: Destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956067/ruby-destructors)

*#initialize* starts functions when a class is instantiated. Just wondering if there's an *#uninitialize* function. For example:

```
class Something
  def initialize
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome #opens browser
  end

  def stuff(url)
    @browser.goto url
  end

  def uninitalize
    @browser.quit #close browser
  end
end

s = Something.new
s.stuff("google.ca")
```

In this case, the browser will be opened by the initialize function. Is there a way to automatically quit it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956067/ruby-destructors for how to use destructor methods in Ruby.

Comment: Why not put `@browser.stuff(url); @browser.quit` directly into #initialize if you want the object to handle everything internally instead of responding to messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Ruby Finalizers Aren't Really Destructors

While you can define [finalizers](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-define_finalizer) for Ruby objects, they aren't really destructors as such. In fact, they aren't triggered until *after* the object is destroyed. The docs say:

> define_finalizer(obj, aProc=proc())
>   Adds aProc as a finalizer, to be called after obj was destroyed.

#### Rethink Your Approach

Rather than instantiating your browser instance with #new, consider a pattern more like:

```
class Something
  attr_accessor :browser

  def start_browser
  end

  def quit_browser
  end
end

s = Something.new
s.start_browser
s.quit_browser
```

Other patterns are also possible, including setting callbacks or timers within your object. Ultimately, the point is that objects should go out of scope and be garbage collected---they can't actually destroy themselves.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any resources that further elaborate on that approach?